# Getting ORA-00904: invalid identifier for a numeric column although it is present in the database

Tags: oracle, ora-00904

I tried to run below query on oracle database

```
select distinct LABEL,EVENT_DATETIME,USL,LSL from 
(select eventTbl.LABEL,eventTbl.EVENT_DATETIME,limitTbl.USL,limitTbl.LSL from EVENT_TABLE eventTbl
          INNER JOIN LIMITS_TABLE limitTbl on limitTbl.start_date <= eventTbl.EVENT_DATETIME
          AND limitTbl.end_date >= eventTbl.EVENT_DATETIME where eventTbl.plant_id = 'plant1')
```

That gives the below error:

ORA-00904: "LIMITTBL"."LSL": invalid identifier

904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

The DDL of LIMITTBL table is

```
create table LIMITS_TABLE(
plant_id varchar2(80),
start_date date,
end_date date,
USL number(11,5),
LSL number(11,5)
);
```

Comment: If you remove the LSL column from your query does the error go away? Out of habit, in Oracle I never mix case of identifers. Everything is always uppercase

Comment: If I remove LSL, it complains for USL. If I remove both, the query works fine

Comment: So when you remove it from the outside part it stops complaining? If you use `select distinct * from` in the outside part, does it return the columns you expect?

Comment: Yes, It complains the same if I remove from outside part and use "select distinct * from"

Comment: Are you certain you are using the table in the schema you think you are? This is going to be one of those things where there is some specific environmental thing causing it. If you run the SQL inside the brackets, I take it you get the same error? What if you just run `SELECT LSL FROM LIMITS_TABLE`? If you run `SELECT * FROM LIMITS_TABLE` do you see the `LSL` column? I predict this Q is deleted in 10 minutes when you work out what has happened

Comment: Looks like USL and LSL columns don't exist in LIMITTBL table. Could you post tables' descriptions?

Comment: Yes. When I run `SELECT * FROM LIMITS_TABLE` or `SELECT LSL FROM LIMITS_TABLE` I can see the values

Comment: @Littlefoot
create table LIMITS_TABLE(
plant_id varchar2(80),
start_date date,
end_date date,
USL number(11,5),
LSL number(11,5)
);

Comment: Did you, by any chance, create table and/or columns using **double quotes** and lower/mixed letter case?

Comment: Cannot replicate the problem as your query works [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/POXqN7vl). (Your query could also be simpler - see the fiddle for an example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too much code to put into a comment; if columns really existed, your code would have worked:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     event_table AS (SELECT 'plant1' plant_id, 'A' label, SYSDATE event_datetime FROM DUAL),
  3     limits_table
  4     AS
  5        (SELECT 1 usl, 2 lsl, SYSDATE start_date, SYSDATE + 2 end_date FROM DUAL)
  6  SELECT DISTINCT LABEL,
  7                  EVENT_DATETIME,
  8                  USL,
  9                  LSL
 10    FROM (
 11            SELECT eventTbl.LABEL,
 12                   eventTbl.EVENT_DATETIME,
 13                   limitTbl.USL,
 14                   limitTbl.LSL
 15              FROM EVENT_TABLE  eventTbl
 16                   INNER JOIN LIMITS_TABLE limitTbl
 17                      ON     limitTbl.start_date <= eventTbl.EVENT_DATETIME
 18                         AND limitTbl.end_date >= eventTbl.EVENT_DATETIME
 19             WHERE eventTbl.plant_id = 'plant1'
 20         );

LABEL EVENT_DATE        USL        LSL
----- ---------- ---------- ----------
A     11.10.2023          1          2

SQL>
```

However, as I commented - if you enclosed column names into double quotes and used lower/mixed letter case, query would have failed; see line #5:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     event_table AS (SELECT 'plant1' plant_id, 'A' label, SYSDATE event_datetime FROM DUAL),
  3     limits_table
  4     AS
  5        (SELECT 1 "usl", 2 "LsL", SYSDATE start_date, SYSDATE + 2 end_date FROM DUAL)
  6  SELECT DISTINCT LABEL,
  7                  EVENT_DATETIME,
  8                  USL,
  9                  LSL
 10    FROM (
 11            SELECT eventTbl.LABEL,
 12                   eventTbl.EVENT_DATETIME,
 13                   limitTbl.USL,
 14                   limitTbl.LSL
 15              FROM EVENT_TABLE  eventTbl
 16                   INNER JOIN LIMITS_TABLE limitTbl
 17                      ON     limitTbl.start_date <= eventTbl.EVENT_DATETIME
 18                         AND limitTbl.end_date >= eventTbl.EVENT_DATETIME
 19             WHERE eventTbl.plant_id = 'plant1'
 20         );
                 limitTbl.LSL
                 *
ERROR at line 14:
ORA-00904: "LIMITTBL"."LSL": invalid identifier
```

If that's the case, you'll have to use double quotes and the same letter case every time you reference that column (lines #7, 8, 13, 14):

```
SQL> WITH
  2     event_table AS (SELECT 'plant1' plant_id, 'A' label, SYSDATE event_datetime FROM DUAL),
  3     limits_table
  4     AS
  5        (SELECT 1 "usl", 2 "LsL", SYSDATE start_date, SYSDATE + 2 end_date FROM DUAL)
  6  SELECT DISTINCT LABEL,
  7                  EVENT_DATETIME,
  8                  "usl",
  9                  "LsL"
 10    FROM (
 11            SELECT eventTbl.LABEL,
 12                   eventTbl.EVENT_DATETIME,
 13                   limitTbl."usl",
 14                   limitTbl."LsL"
 15              FROM EVENT_TABLE  eventTbl
 16                   INNER JOIN LIMITS_TABLE limitTbl
 17                      ON     limitTbl.start_date <= eventTbl.EVENT_DATETIME
 18                         AND limitTbl.end_date >= eventTbl.EVENT_DATETIME
 19             WHERE eventTbl.plant_id = 'plant1'
 20         );

LABEL EVENT_DATE        usl        LsL
----- ---------- ---------- ----------
A     11.10.2023          1          2

SQL>
```